# Stuck - My own implementation of Multi-dimensional Binary Search

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm a bit stuck on my own implementation of a Binary search of a 2D array. It does not seem to iterate into the next row and remains in the same column (thus a never-ending loop). The way a binary search works is to start at the middle between two endpoints (a low and high-end point). If the query is too low, then the high endpoint is readjusted to be the middle point - 1. If the query is too high, then the low endpoint is set to be the mid endpoint + 1. All of this happens until either the query is found, or there are no matches thus resulting in a worst case scenario of O(log n). However, I can't seem to get the array to go row by row and search for values. Here is what I have done so far:

```
public static int count(int[][]array, int query) {

        int countoccurences = 0;        
        int low = 0;                        
        int high = array[0].length - 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
                while (low <= high) {

                    int mid = (low + high) / 2; //Set mid point to be (low + high) divided by 2
                    if (array[row][mid] == query ) { //Check if middle value in each column is equal to the search query
                            countoccurences++; //If it is, increment countoccurences by 1
                        } else if (array[row][mid] < query) {
                            low = mid + 1; //If it is less than query then re-adjust low to be mid index + 1
                        } else  {                           
                            high = mid - 1; //if query is too low, re-adjust high to be mid index - 1
                        } 
                } 
            }
        }   


        return countoccurences;


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = { {7, 4, 3, 5, 10},{8, 5, 4, 6, 11},{10, 10, 8, 10, 13}, {11, 10, 15, 10, 14}};
        System.out.println("Total occurences of the number 10 is: " + count(array, 10));
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Binary search requires sorted data. Your `array` is not sorted. To count the instances of the number 10 there is no point in doing a binary search, you may as well do a 2D loop over the array and +1 to a counter every time you see a variable

Comment: It's the columns that are sorted, and not the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
    public static int count(int[][] array, int query)
    {
        // nothing to find in an empty array
        if(array.length == 0)
            return 0;

        int countoccurences = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++)
        {
            int low = 0;
            int high = array.length - 1;
            while (low <= high)
            {
                int mid = (low + high) / 2; //Set mid point to be (low + high) divided by 2
                if (array[mid][column] == query)
                {
                    // Check if middle value in each column is equal to the search query
                    for (int row = low; row <= high; row++)
                    {
                        if (array[row][column] == query)
                            countoccurences++; //If it is, increment countoccurences by 1
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if (array[mid][column] < query)
                {
                    low = mid + 1; //If it is less than query then re-adjust low to be mid index + 1
                }
                else
                {
                    high = mid - 1; //if query is too low, re-adjust high to be mid index - 1
                }
            }

        }
        return countoccurences;
    }
```

Important changes:

- swapped rows and columns to match your actual sorting directions of your data
- introduced `break;` for case when there is query in the column. This is the reason of the infinite loop in your code
- removed outer `for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++)` as it makes no sense
- on the other hand, added inner `for (int row = low; row <= high; row++)`. It should cover case when there are several target values in the same row such as column #3 in your data. This inner loop also can be made to use more effective binary-search but I'm too lazy.